# Flushed my Engine on a 2010 Altima

Tags: engine, flush

I stupidly was sold an engine flush on the 2010 altima with 160k miles.

I am just wondering if I can expect my car to die in the next week or 2, or is it possible that it wont harm my car and I will get lucky or is it a guaranteed destroyed of cars.

Thanks

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to use engine flushes for the oil system, but never heard of one destroying anything.

Comment: I now know its a bad idea but I have heard some horror stories of flushing and engine on an older miles car and then the engine dying since there was no more sludge.

Comment: if a flush is the straw that breaks the camels back then your engine was on its deathbed anyway.